# How to execute a piece of code on a certain time

Tags: python, timing

I have a python code which is executed on several hosts. It is supposed to send a message to a coordinator.

```
def foo():
    try:
        #print(time.ctime())
        MESSAGE = str(len(queueList))
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
        sock.sendto(MESSAGE, ('10.0.0.1', 5005))
        threading.Timer(15, foo).start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')
        raise
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

I want all these hosts start executing foo() at a certain time, for example at 3:15. I'm new to Python, so I didn't find anything as my answer. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: use your system scheduler

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This is part of a longer code, I need this part of my code to be executed as a certain time.

Comment: @Pablo you posted a standalone script, I can only answer based on what you posted.

Comment: It might not fit your needs right now, but keep an eye out for bruno's suggestion. Isolating the code that needs to be scheduled and then using `cron` or your platform's scheduler might lead to a more robust and testable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work

```
import datetime
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()


# Define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print text

# The job will be executed on November 6th, 2009
exec_date = datetime.date(2009, 11, 6)
job_time = datetime.datetime.combine(exec_date, datetime.time(23, 59, 8))
# Store the job in a variable in case we want to cancel it
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, job_time, ['text'])

sched.start()
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

try:
    # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: There is an error saying that: ImportError: No module named apscheduler.scheduler

Comment: You need to install apscheduler `pip install apscheduler
`, I have added more code. Kindly use the recent one.

Comment: @Jeril thanks, I installed but there is still an error stating that: ValueError: Not adding job since it would never be run